# C#(winform) 1 usercontrol form and 1 form window, not triggering the usercontrol event after clicking a button in other form window

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 1 usercontrol forms and 1 regular window form. First form(window)trigger an event in the other form, I reference them, when I click a button in form 1 it trigger an event in usercontrol form, it trigger and show a message box in usercontrol, but it doesn't trigger other event there. I want to refresh a datagridview in usercontrol form 1 after I inserted a data, but the datagrid from usercontrol 1 is not refreshing.

To update the datagridview on user control form, from the window form.

I'll post the code when I get back to my computer.

Update: Here is the code.

This code is from Windows Form where the button is that will trigger the "RefreshDataGridView()".

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Insert into SchedpTbl(SchedpFullName,SchedpTime,SchedpDate)Values(@cbPatient,@tPicker,@dPicker)", conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("cbPatient", cbPatient.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("tPicker", tpicker.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("dPicker", dpicker.Text);
conn.Open();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

PageAppointment form2 = new PageAppointment();
form2.RefreshDataGridView();

}
```

This is the code in the Usercontrol form where the datagridview is "todaygrid". I did have proper sql connection or display in this form. everything is showing besides that update/refresh the datagrid.

```
public void RefreshDataGridView()
 {
 todaygrid.Refresh();
 }
```

Comment: This: `PageAppointment form2 = new PageAppointment();` generates a **new instance** of `PageAppointment`; it's not the instance you have already initialized and the one you expect to update. You need the original instance -- Possibly, avoid using Forms like this (if `PageAppointment` is a Form with `TopLevel = false`), use actual UserControls. These have a designer, too

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use delegate.**
Declare a public delegate in the custom control class (in your case it is usercontrol form). Then, declare a method in this class that will have the same input parameters as the delegate. In this method, place the table update code (assign new data to the table and update it).

In a regular window form, you need to initialize the delegate object by assigning it a value equal to the declared method in the usercontrol class (in my example, this is ShowNewValues). Further, you can execute the method through the declared delegate.

For example:

```
public delegate void UpdateValues(List<string> updatedValues);

public class CustomUserControl
{
   public void ShowNewValues(List<string> updatedValues)
   {
      //todo: logic...
   }    
}

public class mainWindow:Window
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      CustomUserControl mControl = new CustomUserControl();
      UpdateValues updateValuesMethod = mControl.ShowNewValues;
      List<string> items = new List<string>(){"test 1", "test 2"};
      updateValuesMethod(items);
   }
}
```

Or you can use **Action** without implementation of delegate:

```
public class CustomUserControl
{
   public void ShowNewValues(List<string> updatedValues)
   {
      //todo: logic...
   }    
}

public class mainWindow:Window
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      CustomUserControl mControl = new CustomUserControl();
      Action updateValuesMethod = mControl.ShowNewValues;
      List<string> items = new List<string>(){"test 1", "test 2"};
      updateValuesMethod(items);
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).